# Type error: cannot read property variable of null of a method

Tags: javascript, oop

I created this `class Cars` with a method `animate` in JavaScript.  I want to create a car prototype. When I try to invoke the method, I keep getting:

`TypeError: cannot read property 'carTag' of null of 'animate'`

I am trying to understand why I keep getting this error.

```
class Cars{
     constructor(carTag){
    //sets up the local variables for the constructor function
         this.carTag = new Image()
         this.carTag.src = carTag
         document.getElementById("gameboard").innerHTML = 
         this.carTag
     }

     animate() {
         const image = this.carTag;
         const animate = this.animate;
         let throttle = 2000;
         const canvas = document.getElementById("gameboard");
         const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
         let x = canvas.width;
         let y = 0;
         setTimeout (function(){
             ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
             ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);                    
             x -=4;
             requestAnimationFrame(animate);
       }, 1000/throttle);
    }
}

 car1 = new Cars("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk0DW.png");
 car1.animate();
```

Thanks for your help!

Update:
The error is caused by 
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

I am trying to figure out why I can't pass the image through this loop.

Thanks for all your help.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Is there any chance you could post the whole class? Thanks.

Comment: Did you instantiate (create/initialize) an object first?  If not, it would be null and there would be nothing to read.

Comment: This should be a lot easier to understand when your class is posted and we can see exactly what is going on. :)

Comment: I thought that if a function is in a class, its called a method.

Comment: I hope this helps better understand the problem.  I am baffled why I get an error message.

Comment: Sorry i did not see that it was a class

Comment: got it working ??

Comment: Nope, I get another type error.

Comment: I added the global variables too if that helps.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Update:  I found the problem.  When I try to use requestAnimationFrame(animate), it gives me that error message.  Why can't I reference an image when I use requestAnimationFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Cars{
    constructor(carTag){
        //sets up the local variables for the constructor function
        this.carTag = carTag
    }
    ...
}
```

Make this change and it will work. your **carTag** was **imgTag**

----------------------------------EDIT-------------------------------------------

image passing done right

First of all Image is already in window object so it is already global

```js
    
    class Cars{
        constructor(carTag){
            //sets up the local variables for the constructor function
            this.carTag = new Image()
            this.carTag.src = carTag
            document.getElementById('abcd').innerHTML = this.carTag
        }
    
        animate() {
            const image = this.carTag;
            const animate = this.animate;
            let throttle = 2000;
            setTimeout (function(){
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
                ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);                    
                x -=4;
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
          }, 1000/throttle);
        }
    }
    
    car1 = new Cars("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk0DW.png")
```

this.carTag is an image object.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Even if imgTag refers to new Image().  I tried doing that then I get this:  Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

Comment: What you were passing through your constructor was carTag but you were assigning self.carTag = imgTag instead of self.carTag = carTag

Comment: I get the same error message.  Thank you though.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: the constructor is correct, the way it has to be. Go through animate though

Comment: You are right.  The constructor is correct.  I found the real problem: requestAnimationFrame gives me: TypeError: cannot read property 'carTag' of null of 'animate'.

Comment: Another question: I am curious why you suggest: document.getElementById('abcd').innerHTML = this.carTag

Comment: That was just a test i did

Answer (score 0):

Inside the animate function, this refers to the animate function itself, not to the object that it is a member of. In your class definition, you can say "var self = this;" and use self.carTag in the animate function. You might still have issues with using self.animate inside the definition of animate though.